# Go paypal REST API request

Tags: paypal, go

So Im currently using Go and Im trying to create a payment for Paypal I been trying this code

```
    payer := &Payer{"paypal"}
    amount := &Amount{"EUR", "12"}
    trans := &Transactions{amount, "A super test"}
    uris := &Redirect_urls{"http://localhost", "http://localhost"}
    p := &Payment{"sale", payer, trans, uris}
    response, err := json.Marshal(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error at PaypalPayment - buy controller")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(response))

    client := &http.Client{}
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(response)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment", buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error at PaypalPayment - buy controller - 2")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.Access_token)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error at PaypalPayment - buy controller - 3")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error at PaypalPayment - buy controller - 4")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(body))
```

I already got the access token, the problem is Im getting this error on the response body (last line)

> MALFORMED_REQUEST

The request Im using is this (as of the println)

```
{
   "Intent":"sale",
   "Payer":{
      "Payment_method":"paypal"
   },
   "Transactions":{
      "Amount":{
         "Currency":"EUR",
         "Total":"12"
      },
      "Description":"Super test"
   },
   "Redirect_urls":{
      "Return_url":"http://localhost",
      "Cancel_url":"http://localhost"
   }
}
```

At my eyes seems a good request... no idea what im missing
[image: Error image]

Comment: I don't know that this is the problem but using localhost as a redirect url is probably not allowed. Most servers will fail requests that send it along for purposes like that because it could expose a security vulnerability. Can you link to the docs for this request? In order to say if it's good or bad I gotta be able to compare it to what the API is expecting. Also, status code and any other information from the response body would generally be helpful.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment thats how the request shall look like - As for using localhost well the problem is not there (I guess) since it says its malformed

Comment: The error MALFORMED_REQUEST on paypal docs says Incoming JSON request does not map to API request

Comment: That would imply the requests url is wrong but I don't think that's the case. Your request body seems fine. Can you get a good response from any other requests to that server?

Comment: Well yeah I make 1 request at first to get an oauth token and everything works fine

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't have any other advice than to trouble shoot it by stripping down your request to only the required arguments, getting something to work, then adding in more and more data until you have what you want working. Based on the docs and information above I'd expect the request to succeed. Have you tried doing the same with curl? If you can make the request you want work through curl then you at least know there is something wrong with the Go code.

Comment: The docs show lowercase `payer` but you've got `Payer`. It's probably dying on the case difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was transactions needed to be an array. how blind I am

```
Transactions []*Transactions `json:"transactions"`
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @jcbwlkr you're casing doesn't match what is in the docs. If you don't have json tags on your types you'll have to add them. You have to keep the property names uppercase in Go because it's what marks the fields as being exported. If you're not familiar with this do a search for 'unexported vs exported fields golang'

For example your `Payment` structs definition needs to look like this;

```
type Payment struct {
     Amount *Amount `json:"amount"`
     Transactions *Transactions `json:"transactions"`
     RdUrls *Redirect_urls `json:"redirect_urls"`
}
```

Also, just fyi you can use nest those declarations where you declare the payment so you don't have to assign to local instances of `Amount`, `Transactions` and `Redirect_urls` in order to do the declaration.

It's just like;

```
p := &Payment{"sale", payer, &Transactions{amount, "A super test"}, uris}
```

Comment: @AlvaroCarvajalNakosmai did you apply it recursively through all your types? Notice all their property names are lower cased. I can't see any difference between your schema and the one implemented in their example if that is the case.

Comment: Yeah on all structs. no idea what else to do

Comment: @AlvaroCarvajalNakosmai I'm running out of ideas. Couple things, firstly in their docs it shows the error string as `MALFORMED_REQUEST_ERROR` that's not what you posted in the question. Was that a mistake on your part? Is the value returned from their API different than what is documented? Can you verify the response is in fact from PayPal and not from an intermediary service like Akamai? If the error your getting is the documented one and the response comes directly from PayPal the only remaining advice I have is to contact them directly.

Comment: I added a pic of the body response Im getting

Comment: @AlvaroCarvajalNakosmai when I get a minute I'll follow the link they returned. That response is certainly not what is documented in the broader documents location so I'm pretty skeptical that PayPal is upholding their end of the bargain here.